# Is the "Light Walker" dentist's tool effective at many issues?

Tags: dentistry, infection

In my local newspaper a little while ago, there was a full-page article (can't find an online copy) on a local dentist who uses a device called ["The Light Walker"](http://www.fotona.com/en/products/1188/lightwalker/), supposedly made by a group in Siberia. A wide variety of claims were made by the dentist;

1. It can greatly reduce the pain of treatment,
2. It can be used *instead* of anesthetics in some cases,
3. It can even be used to cut flesh painlessly; the dentist gave an ancedote where one of his children had a lip deformation, and he was able to surgically repair it.
4. Supposedly, it cost him somewhere around $200,000.

Googling "The Light Walker" brings up a massive list of claims, including

1. It has a [12 watt laser with a "Quantum Square Pulse?"](http://www.prnewswire.com/news-releases/fotona-launches-the-new-st-pro-lightwalker-dental-laser-at-the-151st-midwinter-meeting-of-the-chicago-dental-society-booth-4815-300218524.html)
2. [It can "treat" infections?](https://www.draraelmajian.ca/dental/lightwalker-dental-laser/)
3. [It produces "photoacoustic waves"?](http://www.t4med.com/lightwalker.html)

Are dental lasers a thing, and are they as effective as claimed?

Comment: Certainly dental lasers are common in the US.  I have no info on "Light Walker" however.

Comment: So, how is this thing supposed to work? Tricking skin neurons into not realising there is widespread structural damage going on might be ... tricky.